# Kernel Driver Execution Flow ( Faster Than IDA or BinNavi )

Tags: windows, dynamic-analysis, kernel-mode

Is there any tool help my to draw kernel-mode execution flow graph (basic block based or function based) ?

My exact problem is **slow speed**.

---

To clear my question lets ask this way:
*Is there any fast way to draw kernel-mode execution* ?

I use IDA 6.2 pro and BinNavy 5 to generate EF-Graph. They are so slow and have many problems with loops and rep-prefixed.

As I mentioned in my comment the driver initializing tracing wast 30 min (I want to draw each IOCtl graph).

Again as I mentioned in my comment I use Virtual-KD and VMWare (Is it any faster configuration ?).

**1.I'm not in user mode.**

**2.problem is slow speed.**

Comment: Duplicate of [Highlight Executed Basic Blocks in IDA](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/highlight-executed-basic-blocks-in-ida)

Comment: There are many many kernels out there. I think tagging this as Windows would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to [IDA](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=92), since it supports kernel-mode debugging, and has a trace feature.

Comment: Testing IDA with VirtualKD and trying to trace initial phase left about 30 min. is it Normal or any better tool chain I should use?