# IDA Pro monitor applications function calls

Tags: ida, functions

is there a function in IDA Pro to monitor all function calls of an application?
So for example if I import an application into IDA it gives me functions like "sub_45E5C6", right?
And now my question is if IDA can log function calls while the application is running (maybe with the debugger?). So I can minimize the window and see which was the last executed funtion.

Any help would be great!

Comment: See [Highlight Executed Basic Blocks in IDA](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/highlight-executed-basic-blocks-in-ida)

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Google didn't find anything but this really helped!